# Pandas.Dataframe.drop does not drop the specified columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import deque
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import yfinance as yf

import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random



TickerII = yf.Ticker('USDJPY=X')
        
abc = TickerII.history(start="2021-11-29", end="2021-12-09", interval="5m")

abcd = pd.DataFrame(abc)

abcd.drop(['Dividends', 'Stock Splits'], axis = 1)

abcd.head
```

This is my code so far. Importing the Data from yfinance works fine.
The abcd.drop function just does not drop the specified columns.
abcd.head returns all columns imported form yfinance. No error Message is displayed
Output of .head is 7 columns including dividends and stock splits
What am I doing wrong here

Comment: You need to assign the output (`abcd=abcd.drop(['Dividends', 'Stock Splits'], axis = 1)`), or pass `inplace=True` in the `drop()` call

Comment: G.Anderson thank you for your help. Your solution worked perfectly.